# Could there be a physical explanation for a relatively large tangential shear value at large distances from a galaxy cluster?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, gravitational-lensing, weak-lensing, stress-strain

Shown here is a plot of a tangential shear profile, generated by stacking the tangential shear profiles of 64 fields of galaxy clusters.

[image]

The outer distance is about 2.5 times the radius of a cluster peak, so one would expect the tangential shear measurements to converge here. However, as you can see there is a sudden spike at the end.

Further information: the cosmology used here is a plus $\sigma_8=0.9$ and minus $\sigma_8=0.7$ about the fiducial cosmology; the typical radius of a cluster in this sample is about 8 arcmins; within a given cluster peak, the red shifts of the galaxies range from about 0.5 to 1.

Is there a physical explanation for this?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information? What is the typical distance/redshift of the clusters in your sample, or in other words what physical scale corresponds to 1arcmin here? I wonder whether you might be picking up a signal from the typical scale of BAOs or something (I'd guess no, but worth checking if the distance is right anyway).

Comment: Edited. Let me know if you think any more information might be useful? By the way, the data is taken from the recent CFHT survey release.

Comment: Still missing the distances (or systemic redshifts) of the clusters, which would allow a conversion from arcmin to kpc. Would also be useful to know the mass distribution of the clusters.

Comment: @KyleOman Sorry I've only just got back to you! It turned out that there was an error in my code in calculating the shear values.

Comment: That's almost always the explanation ;)